# Como ordenar uma lista em ordem alfabética?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Possuo um `List<ListaUsuarios>` e quero ordena-lo em ordem alfabética por nome

---

**Meu código esta assim**

Classe Usuario:

```
public class Usuario{
   private String nome;
   private String empresa;
   private int    idade;
   private String email;

   public Usuario(String nome, String empresa, int idade, String email){
       this.nome    = nome;
       this.empresa = empresa;
       this.idade   = idade;
       this.email   = email;
   }

   //...GETs E SETs PARA TODAS AS VARIAVEIS GLOBAIS . . .
}
```

classe ListaUsuario:

```
public class ListaUsuario{
    private Usuario user;
    private int     codigo;
    private int     nivel;
    private boolean ativo;


    public ListaUsuario(Usuario user, int codigo, int nivel, boolean ativo){
        this.user   = user;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nivel  = nivel;
        this.ativo  = ativo;
    }

   //...GETs e SETs PARA TODAS AS VARIAVEIS GLOBAIS . . .
}
```

---

Crio minha `List`desta forma:
`List<ListaUsuario> = new Arraylist<>();`

Após isso populo ela com N items do tipo `ListaUsuario`

---

Como posso ordenar ela em ordem alfabética pelo nome do Usuario?

Comment: Tem vários exemplos no site.

Comment: Obrigado, vou estudar em cima deles!

Answer (score -1):

Você deve querer algo parecido como este exemplo creio eu

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;    

public class HashtableDemo {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] companies = { "Yahoo", "Vodafone", "Samsung" };

      System.out.println("Array de String Ordenada em Ordem Crescente: ");
      printNumbers(companies);
  }
}
```

Sua saída será como abaixo

```
Samsung
Vodafone
Yahoo
```

Comment: Me parece que a ordenação ocorre em printNumbers(companies); tem como atualizar a resposta com o escopo deste método?